# Add something at the end of every typed command

Tags: terminal

Is there a possibility to add some text at the end of every command i type in the terminal? For example i type "ps" and after pressing enter, it becomes "ps -a", I type "ls" and it's "ls -a"

Comment: And `rm` becomes `rm -a`, and you get an error message for an invalid option? (same for `mv`) Are you sure you want to add that to each and every command line?

Comment: It's a very specific setup, not going to use commands which doesn't have `-a` option

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create an alias in your .bashrc (hidden and located in user home directory)

Just add the following lines to your .bashrc:

```
alias ls='ls -a'
alias ps='ps -a'
```

and then run the command to source your .bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Doing this will now cause every ls to also show hidden files (files starting with a .) and every ps you run to show all processes except both session leaders and processes not associate with a terminal.

Comment: Simple and reliable

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with a shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    echo "\$ \c"
    read command
    [ $command == "quit" ] && break
    eval $command -a
done
```